# Is there real materials have Lieb lattice structure?

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, crystals

Is there real materials have Lieb lattice structure?

Some examples?

Comment: Please see the [faq] and [How To Ask](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). Currently, this question is (a) make-a-list-y, and (b) shows no research effort, so I'm closing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plenty! The CuO$_2$ planes of cuprate superconductors are perhaps the most famous example, but in fact a lot of layered oxides are going to coordinate in this fashion. The Lieb lattice is essentially a two-dimensional counterpart of the "perovskite" structure, which is ubiquitous in nature.

Comment: Thank you very much! Although the question has already been closed.